# Inserting rows into mysql table fails

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to write code that inserts fields into a database based on a SELECT query.

The following is my `SELECT` code

```
<?php
    $sql = ("select * from category"); 
    $result = $con->query($sql); 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $cat_id=$row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title=$row['cat_title'];
            echo "<option value=".$cat_id." >".$cat_title."</option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

this is my inserting script

```
$title = validateInput($_POST['title']);
$desc1 = validateInput($_POST['desc1']);
//$content = validateInput($_POST['content']);
$cat_title = validateInput($_POST['cat_title']);
$cat_id = validateInput($_POST['cat_id']);

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title,desc1,cat_title, img, img1,img2,img3,zip,user_id,cat_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $title, $desc1,$category,$img, $img1,$img2,$img3,$zip, $user_id,$cat_title,$cat_id);
if($stmt->execute()){
     //echo "<script>alert('Your project added successfully');
     echo "<script>alert('Your project added successfully  ')</script>
<script>setTimeout(\"self.history.back();\",0000);</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Failed added your project');</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: There is nothing about inserting in your PHP code. Can you please clarify?

Comment: i added my inserting products  PHP file

Comment: Hey check out my updated answer. I think I found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting parameters that are missing in the INSERT parameters, you stipulate 11 fields but enter only 10. Replace your code with below:

```
$title     = validateInput($_POST['title']);
$desc1     = validateInput($_POST['desc1']);
//$content = validateInput($_POST['content']);
$cat_title = validateInput($_POST['cat_title']);
$cat_id    = validateInput($_POST['cat_id']);

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title,desc1,cat_title,img,img1,img2,img3,zip,user_id,cat_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $title,$desc1,$cat_title,$img, $img1,$img2,$img3,$zip,$user_id,$cat_id);
if($stmt->execute()){
    //echo "<script>alert('Your project added successfully');
    echo "<script>alert('Your project added successfully  ')</script>
    <script>setTimeout(\"self.history.back();\",0000);</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Failed added your project');</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would probably also fail. Check my answer. I think it is because `$cat_title` will be inserted into `user_id` which would have type mismatch, right?

Comment: Riz-waan, yep. I just saw your answer, I really had something confusing over there in the query ;P

Comment: but display like this Notice: Undefined index: cat_title in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\upload-source.php on line 257

Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\upload-source.php on line 258

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\upload-source.php on line 277

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title,desc1,cat_title, img, img1,img2,img3,zip,user_id,cat_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $title, $desc1,$category,$img, $img1,$img2,$img3,$zip, $user_id,$cat_title,$cat_id);
```

This is your original code, the problem is is that your insert into products the `$cat_title` should be between `$desc1` and `$category`.

This should work:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title,desc1,cat_title, img, img1,img2,img3,zip,user_id,cat_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssii", $title, $desc1,$cat_title,$img, $img1,$img2,$img3,$zip, $user_id,$cat_id);
```

You also only have ten columns but were trying to insert 11 columns worth of information.

You would have to parse the user Id and Cat ID as integer instead of string. Now this updated code should work. You would have to bind the parameter with `ssssssssii`

Comment: i checked this line but display same results not inserting cat_it

Comment: i checked but not inserting

Comment: like this error Notice: Undefined index: cat_title in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\upload-source.php on line 257

Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\upload-source.php on line 258

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\zblog\upload-source.php on line 277

Comment: @ranjeewa What is upload-source.php?

Comment: user uploading projects file  upload-source.php this is blog

Comment: @ranjeewa are any of the columns being uploaded?

Comment: @ranjeewa Can you try echoing $cat_id to make sure it has value?

Comment: this script is there error $sql = ("select * from category"); 
$result = $con->query($sql); 
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$cat_id = validateInput($_POST['cat_id']);
$cat_title= validateInput($_POST['cat_title']);
echo '<option>'.$row['cat_title'].'</option>';

Comment: I am confused now

Comment: $cat_title = validateInput($_POST['cat_title']);
$cat_id = validateInput($_POST['cat_id']);